# Oracle Trigger Spool Csv - Generate a csv file from select in oracle

Tags: oracle

is there a way to make a trigger after update that make a csv file from oracle

i got sql that make me a resault that i need

```
    select 
(lower(substr(cp.fname,1,1) || translate(convert(cp.lname, 'AL32UTF8', 'UTF8'),'ón','on'))
 || ',' || 
 cpel.internal_display_name 
 || ',' || 
 cpel.org_name 
 || ',' || 
 cpel.pos_title) 
 as "login,name,dep,tit" 
 from company_pers_emp_lov cpel, company_pers cp
where cp.emp_no = cpel.emp_no and cp.emp_no like 'P%' 
ORDER BY cpel.emp_no DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

the resault of sql is

login,name,dep,tit
xyyyyy,xxxxx yyyyy,department,tittle

Answer (score 0):

I'd  generally make use of [**Tim Hall 's Generic Solution**](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/generating-csv-files#custom-sql)  with a custom [**CSV package**](https://oracle-base.com/dba/script?category=miscellaneous&file=csv.sql) that has a procedure `generate` which takes any directory ,filename and query  as an argument and dumps the result of the query into a CSV file using `UTL_FILE`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY EXTRACT_DIR  AS '/tmp/extracts';   --some path
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY EXTRACT_DIR TO <trigger_owner>; --or who executes.
```

You may then put this in your Procedure/Trigger or whatever that needs to output to a CSV file.

```
csv.generate('EXTRACT_DIR', 'emp.csv', p_query => 'SELECT * FROM employees');
```